# "list iterator not dereferencable" on creation of object

Tags: c++

I'm creating a computer graphics project using C++ and QT in visual studio.

The line I'm getting this error on is

```
quad *bodyQuad = &quad(bodyTri1, bodyTri2);
```

in the following method:

```
void MyGLWidget::createCharacter1(tree *t, node *root) {
    triangle bodyTri1 = triangle(vec3(4, 0, 0), vec3(-1, 1, 0));
    triangle bodyTri2 = triangle(vec3(-6, 0, 0), vec3(-1, -1, 0));
    bodyTri2 = *bodyTri2.applyTransform(mat3::translation2D(5, 1));
    quad *bodyQuad = &quad(bodyTri1, bodyTri2);
    root = new node(bodyQuad, 2);
}
```

`triangle` and `quad` are both derived from a virtual `shape` class. The `shape` class has a `std::list` in it for storing vertices.

`node` also has an `std::list` for storing its children.

In the constructor of both `triangle` and `quad` the vertices are added to the list

## triangle's constructor

```
triangle::triangle(const vec3& vector1, const vec3& vector2) {
    numTriangles = 1;
    isOneColor = true;
    vec3 origin = vec3(0, 0, 1);// '1' to signify a point
    data = mat3(vector1, vector2, origin);
    data = data.transpose();

    //push "origin" vertex
    vertices.push_back(data[2]);
    //make sure point/vector convention followed, and push "base" vertex
    vertices.push_back(data[0] + vec3(0, 0, 1));
    //make sure point/vector convention followed, and push "height" vertex
    vertices.push_back(data[1] + vec3(0, 0, 1));

}
```

## quad's constructor

```
quad::quad(triangle triangle1, triangle triangle2) {

    numTriangles = 2;
    isOneColor = true;

    data[0] = triangle1;
    data[1] = triangle2;

    std::list<vec3> tri1Vertices = data[0].getVertices();
    std::list<vec3> tri2Vertices = data[1].getVertices();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < tri1Vertices.size(); i++) {
        vertices.push_back(tri1Vertices.front());
        tri1Vertices.pop_front();
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < tri2Vertices.size(); i++) {
        vertices.push_back(tri2Vertices.front());
        tri2Vertices.pop_front();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's too much code. Please condense it down to a [mcve].

Comment: I'm guessing you need something like `quad *bodyQuad = new quad(bodyTri1, bodyTri2);`. Taking the address of a temporary is not going to work.

Comment: `&quad(bodyTri1, bodyTri2);` creates a new temporary variable; gets the pointer to it; then destroys the temporary.

Comment: The error message does not match the error.  `quad *bodyQuad = &quad(bodyTri1, bodyTri2);` should say that the addressof operator(`&`) cannot be called on an rvalue.

Comment: changing to `new quad` from `&quad` doesn't fix my current issue, but thank you for pointing out a potential future issue I would have had!

Comment: @RSahu it has been condensed, thank you

Comment: you get the same error with the `new quad` fix?

Comment: @ChandlerThompson, it is condensed but it is not complete. Unless I can copy and paste the code in my setup and compile it, I don't think I can be of much help.

Comment: Are you sure the error doesn't stem from the line `bodyTri2 = *bodyTri2.applyTransform(mat3::translation2D(5, 1));`? Hard to tell since you haven't included the declaration

Comment: @pm100 correct
@UnholySheep visual studio points the error as happening on the `quad` line, but I will include the code from `applyTransform()` for you to look at.
@RSahu I'll see what I can do to simplify the project down to something more manageably testable

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that my `applyTransform()` was returning a `shape` pointer, but in my return statement I was simply dereferencing `&` a temp variable used in `applyTransform()` instead of using the `new` keyword.

Thank you to everyone who helped.